# Why don't we get to indicate the appropriate site for off-topic questions?

Tags: support, bug

When voting to close a question as off-topic in the main site, we have the option to check as reason,

> "This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network"

Then a new window opens... **and the only option we get is that the question belongs to the meta of economics.se.**

I don't know if this is a bug or deliberate, but if it is deliberate, it renders the option totally useless -the point is to be able to select among the SE sites.

I understand that migration itself (decision and execution) is and should be the responsibility of moderators, but we should be able to indicate to them what site we think is the appropriate one, to avoid duplication of effort.

I checked the same feature in Cross Validated, and there, one gets the option, apart from migration to meta, to indicate math.se and stackoverflow.

Then I guess someone, either a moderator or an SE-associate could (and should) add to our choices in the main for off-topic/migration suggestions, the following four sites

https://money.stackexchange.com/

https://quant.stackexchange.com/

https://stats.stackexchange.com/

https://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE**:

Based on [When should we consider adding a default migration path?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261196/when-should-we-consider-adding-a-default-migration-path) and https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/276084/274708
it seems like (1) migration paths are not likely to be added while this site is still in beta, and (2) a migration path is not likely to  be deemed appropriate until we are sending "tens or hundreds" of migrations to a site within each 90 day period (we are currently well short of that level).

For now, please continue to handle migration requests using the flag feature.

---

**Original post**

It seems [we can have a maximum of four](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96205/more-options-when-flagging-for-migration/96345#96345) external sites listed, but I couldn't find an option to add them myself. I [have asked on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/276083/how-do-we-specify-migration-targets-for-our-site) to find out how to get this done.

For the record, we don't actually migrate that much. Here is a complete list of every question that has ever been migrated from econ.SE.

[image]

My understanding is that sites will be added to the migration target list only on the basis of evidence that there are a significant number of migration candidates for that site. Based on the above list, only Money.SE seems to generate a significant number of questions for migration right now so I think it unlikely that sites other than Money.SE will be added to the list.

In the event of a question that belongs on a site other than Money.SE, the relevant response will probably continue to be flagging the question for moderator attention. The mods can migrate to any site and other migration targets can be added to the list if and when we build up a substantial stream of questions that have been migrated to them.

Comment: Let's see how the migration rate changes once we actually can enforce it automatically.