# Should we add more off-topic (migration) reasons?

Tags: discussion

The current off-topic closure reasons are:

[image]

Migration options are also very limited (and, frankly, rather useless [have ever such option be used]):

[image]

According to [this post](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1464/proposal-for-custom-off-topic-close-reason), these options **can be modified**. Additionally, we have up to [four migration options](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1534/why-dont-we-get-to-indicate-the-appropriate-site-for-off-topic-questions). I would suggest we add quant.SE and money.SE but moderators could provide more insights on migration statistics.

Do you think we need more off-topic alternatives?

Comment: FYI, [beta site cannot have migration paths to other sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/296833/241919).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As moderators, we have the power to edit the off-topic reasons for closure, but as Andrew has mentioned in the comments, we are not able to edit where normal users can request a question be migrated to. The link that says we can have four migration options has an answer at the bottom explaining that while in beta, we sorta need to be migrating a lot of questions to one place for us to request a default migration link.

Seeing as we (still) don't migrate that many questions, I think my suggestion in this case is to just flag a post that you think needs to be migrated to somewhere other than meta.econ.SE.